# How to return array from struct using drizzle?

Tags: solidity, web3js, drizzle

So I have been wondering how to return an array from a struct in drizzle, I can make multiple calls using web3, but it is kinda complex and would like a simpler approach. A simplified contract is listed below, the function to add new files is removed.

```
contract FileList {

   /// @dev struct that contains unique link to image (via IPFS), serial Id, and timestamp
   struct File {
      uint256 id;
      string ipfshash;
      bytes32 filename;
      bytes32[5] tags;
      address owner;
      uint256 timestamp;
   }
   uint256 public constant maxAmountOfFiles = 1000;
   // Owner => files
   mapping(address => File[maxAmountOfFiles]) public files;
   // Owner => last files id
   mapping(address => uint256) public lastIds;
   // consider mapping hash to set of tags

   /// @dev return the tags for a specific file 
   /// @param owner --- address of person who uploaded the file 
   /// @param _index --- the file desired, (first file uploaded, second , etc ...)
   function getFileTags(address owner, uint256 _index) external view returns (bytes32[5]) {
       return files[owner][_index].tags;
  }

}
```

To grab the table from the front-end

```
let table = []
this.drizzle.contracts.FileList.methods.lastIds(this.state.fileOwnerAddress).call()
.then((lastIds) => {
    // eslint-disable-line no-loop-func
   for (let i = 0; i < lastIds; i++) {
     this.drizzle.contracts.FileList.methods.files(this.state.fileOwnerAddress,i).call()
     .then((fileItem) => {
       // add file item to table, missing tags
       fileItem.filename = this.drizzle.web3.utils.hexToUtf8(fileItem.filename)
       fileItem.timestamp = this.timeConverter(fileItem.timestamp)
       /** Can't return bytes from struct array, maybe split this into into another loop?. */
       this.drizzle.contracts.FileList.methods.getFileTags(this.state.fileOwnerAddress,i).call()
       .then((tags) => {
          // console.log(tags)
          // convert all non 0 bytes tag fields to hex
          for (var j=0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (tags[j] !== '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
              // console.log(tags[j])
              tags[j] = this.drizzle.web3.utils.hexToUtf8(tags[j])
            } else {
              // console.log(tags[j])
              tags[j] = 'N/A'
            }
          }
          fileItem.tags = tags
          console.log(tags)
       })
       // console.log(fileItem)
       // add fileItem to table
       table.push(fileItem)
     });
   }
```

If anyone can give suggestions on how to improve my code or somehow load this data in [drizzle](https://github.com/truffle-box/drizzle-box) (right now the bytes32 array is not being returned), that would be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? Currently having trouble displaying a struct with Drizzle-React-Components. Would appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: I cannot remember, I can take a look and see if I remember.

My existing code seems to work, but I consider it suboptimal still.

https://github.com/FriendlyUser/file-track-Dapp

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a basic javascript problem then anything else... I would take a look at es6 some es6 array methods such as `forEeach()`

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_arrays.htm

Essentially what should be done here is creating some small functions to handle the formatting of data. You can then compose your different functions into something a bit cleaner.

Comment: See I think forEach won't work as returning all the data from the blockchain is illadvisable. Especially with a hardcoded limit of 1000. In particular I was wondering if anyone knew how to use the drizzle library to simplify the process.

Comment: maybe that will help for the tag array